# Checking if a function is in the Schwartz space of rapidly decreasing functions.

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

Is there any neat bi-implication other than the definition that I can use to check this? This question was motivated by a question that asked if $ f(x) = e^{-|x|^3}$ was in S. It isn't infinitely differentiable so obviously isn't in S, but it got me thinking.

Thanks in advance.